# Microservices architecture for a system using multiple data providers

Tags: java, spring, architecture, restful-architecture, microservices

I am looking how to properly architect a system I am building.

I'll try to give a high level view of the system's requirements:

- The system uses various data providers (2 for now, but more to come). The data can be retrieved :

  - either directly **from a remote database** (hosted on the provider's server, direct MySQL access)
  - either directly **from files on the local server** (the provider pushes files by SCP). Here there would be to additional logic to check if the files are here and purge them / move them afterwards

The method to use depends on the provider.

- The system then needs to **regularly import data from these providers** to a local database. There is a special importation logic which differs for every provider.

---

Putting all the code in a monolithic application obviously seems like a bad idea, so I'm looking into splitting it into multiple services.

I'm really not sure how to architect this, though, and would appreciate some advice.

Details:

- Java + Spring if needed to expose an API between services
- Scalability / speed not really important (I hate saying that - but in this case it doesn't matter whether the imports take 1 ms or 4 hours)
- Everything needs to be hosted on a single server and no data can leave it (sensible data)

Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: *Putting all the code in a monolithic application obviously seems like a bad idea*: what is obvious about that? From the description you gave, rest, services, etc. are irrelevant. It seems you just need two main classes reading from files or a database, writing to a database, and regularly launched by some cron script, for example. Don't overengineer things. Do the simplest thing that does the job. Not everything needs to be done like Google, Netflix or Amazon do.

Comment: @JBNizet should write it down as an answer and it should be marked as "the" answer. Could not agree more. This sounds like an ETL process.